# What allows us to break up $dy/dx$ in solving a separable differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you had a separable first order differential equation that can be written as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)
$$

Rigourously, what allows us to rearrange this as
$$
\frac{1}{h(y)}dy=g(x)dx?
$$

I'm familiar with differential geometry, and differential $k$-forms, but is there a rigourous explanation of why treating the derivative as a fraction ends up working?

Comment: You've asked two subtly different questions here: (1) what fact about differential forms allows one to deduce $dy/h(y)=g(x)dx$ from $dy/dx = g(x)h(y)$? (2) why does writing $dy/h(y)=g(x)dx$ "work" - which I interpret as: why is the function $y(x)$ derived from $dy/h(y)=g(x)dx$ (by integrating both sides) a solution to $dy/dx = g(x)h(y)$? So to clarify: which of these questions are you interested in having answered?

Comment: @GregMartin I'm primarily interested in the first question (1).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would say then: in a neighborhood where $y=y(x)$ is defined and satisfies $y'(x) = g(x)h(y)$, then the change of variables formula for $1$-forms applied to $dy/h(y)$ would yield $(y'(x) dx)/h(y) = g(x)dx$. Does that sound right? (In particular, this explanation doesn't try to interpret "splitting up the fraction $dy/dx$" as an operation in its own right.)

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks, that makes more sense.